# PERC H310 - Multiple RAID 1 Arrays

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid1, dell-perc

Currently, I have a RAID 1 (using two 1TB disks) configured on PERC H310 controller on a PowerEdge T420 Server. It currently contains Windows Server 2012, a Hyper-v role, applications and SQL Server database. I'd like to add another RAID 1 (using two 2TB disks) for a similar Hyper-V virtual setup. My questions are:

1. Does H310 allows two RAID 1 setups to be made? (I know H700 and H800 do, just not sure about H310).
2. Is it a good configuration considering Hyper-V? My workload on the hyper server will be minimal (10-15 users with moderate database activity).

Comment: It confuse me, what run on the physical server, an hypervisor ? or you have a physical server running 2012 ? that you will add a hyper's role with the hyper-v datastore on another raid ?

Comment: 2012 on the physical server, and a hyper-v role.

Comment: The T4xx is an entry grade server from Dell for virtualization, having a physical sql & application on it and a vm running will hit the performance. What will run in the VM ? I ask as the H310 without upgrade (like memory addon) will certainly choke.

Comment: Same setup as the physical server i.e. 2012, SQL Server, Epicor ERP for testing and training purpose only.

Comment: Posted as a answer, but yes, you should be ok. As it's for testing I worry less :), but be aware the H310 can become a serious bottleneck.

Comment: Do you suggest upgrade or adding memory?

Comment: If the VM is only for testing, and is mostly idle, no, but you will be able to see the impact. As it's for testing, if it impact you got the leasure to be able to close it, not like a VM in production. (and you order the kit after, as it cost high)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H310 supports up to 32 physical and 16 virtual disks. You will be ok to create two raid 1.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual and Physical disks have nothing to do with new "Disk Groups", which is what you configure for another RAID.  The format is Disk Group 0, 1, 2, etc.  Under which, you have Virtual disks 0, 1, 2, etc, and physical disks, 0, 1, 2, etc.

When on VD Mgmt section in controller config mode, select the PERC at the top, then F2, which will bring up your menu to create a new VD (which is a disk group actually, which if you had Disk Group 0 as RAID 5 for instance, the next will be Disk Group 1 with whatever RAID you choose, and then you have VD's and PD's under that like I previously stated.).